# R: explanation of ecdf(x)(xs)

Tags: r

**Variables**

```
x <- father.son$fheight
xs <- seq(floor(min(x)),ceiling(max(x)),0.1)
```

**Functions/Plots**

```
ecdf(x)(xs)
plot(xs,ecdf(x)(xs),type="l",xlab="Height in inches",ylab="F(x)")
```

**Question**

I am confused as to what the two variables following the `ecdf` function do. I have looked at the help file but it only illustrates what happens when there is one variable following `ecdf`. I can see what `ecdf(x)(xs)` produces empirically and how the values of the result fit into the `plot`. But, I do not understand the syntax/mechanics of `ecdf(x)(xs)` having two variables. If you can provide an explanation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `ecdf` is a function. `ecdf(x)` is a _function call_ (i.e. it invokes the function `ecdf`). But, unusually, the object that the call `ecdf(x)` returns is not a vector or a list, but is actually itself a function. For example, you could do `myfunc <- ecdf(x)`. Now `myfunc` is a function, and you can do `myfunc(xs)`. The expression `ecdf(x)(xs)` just cuts out the middle-man.